# Evoking emission spectrum in practice

Tags: spectroscopy

I am a student in robotic assocciation and I designed working spectrometer for UV-Vis emission spectrum. The issue is evoking emission spectrum. The spectrometer is designed to be working on board of martian rover. Can I evoke the emission by shining the rock samples with UV lamp or X-ray lamp? We can't use laser beams or burn the sample due to onboard safety. Are there any other methods of obtaining one?

Comment: I would like to illuminate rock samples which simulates martian soil and based on the results state its compostition. I am aiming for atomic emission spectra. I tried tungsten lamp but I got continous spectrum at the detector

Comment: Small edit: we are aiming for visible and near UV spectrum

Comment: Since you want atomic emission spectra, you either have to use LIBS (laser induced breakdown spectroscopy), like on the actual Martian rovers, or you need to make an atom reservoir using something like arc-spark or DC plasma spectroscopy. No light bulb or LED source will do what you want. The technique of x ray induced fluorescence requires an x ray source and likely a better spectrometer than you may have and it is not really what you want anyway. Heating rock samples with a flame or plasma, in the open, is also unlikely to work. Sorry.

Comment: Please have a look at this 5 page document, especially the right hand side of fig. 3.9: https://spie.org/samples/PM253.pdf. It will not be easy at all, but not much that is worthwhile is easy. Good luck!

Comment: However if we would change our mind, how powerful laser would we need?